# ionic 3 Server Showing some old Page that i deleted

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

After deleting My HomePage to create my own one In ionic 3
sometime the ionic serve display an error that say the following :
Cannot find the module **'../pages/home/home'.**
in the file **app.module.ts**

---

File app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

File app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage = 'ProfileSearchPage';

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }
}
```

i have one page only in the folder
[Here the folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2pkF.png)

Comment: What's up in your app.component.ts you gotta delete related stuff in there too

Comment: there is nothing there i removed everything and the error show up

Comment: relaunch ionic server

Comment: even that not working

Comment: You can give it try to relaunch your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just file search "pages/home/home" and see where the reference is, then delete it.

Comment: i would do that if there is one i searched all the file for it no result

Comment: you gotta check the imports too